# Python Requests - Using variables within header and get request

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I have two variables that must be injected into a PUT (curl -XPOST equivalent)

- Variable1 (header)
- Variable2 (part of the URL)

  ```
  headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer Variable1',
  }

  files = [
  ('server', '*'),
  ]

  requests.get('https://URL/1/2/3/4/5/Variable2', headers=headers, files=files, verify=False)
  ```

I'm running into two issues:

1. What is the proper way to include variables into the request
2. Since this is run across HTTPS, how do I validate what is actually included within the request? I'd like to validate this for debugging purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. What is the proper way to include variables into the request

Passing the headers dictionary as the `headers` argument, as you have it written, is fine.  For your url string, I would just `join()` the base URL to your Variable2, and pass that as an argument.

Here's how I would write this code:

```
import requests

base_url = 'https://URL/1/2/3/4/5/'
url = ''.join([base_url, Variable2])

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer Variable1',}
files = [('server', '*'),]

resp = requests.put(url, headers=headers, files=files, verify=False)
```

> 2. Since this is run across HTTPS, how do I validate what is actually included within the request? I'd like to validate this for debugging purposes

You can utilize the [`PreparedRequest`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#prepared-requests) object:

```
from requests import Request, Session

r = Request('PUT', url, headers=headers, files=files)
prepped = r.prepare()

# now, for example, you can print out the url, headers, method...
# whatever you need to validate in your request.
# for example:
# print prepped.url, prepped.headers

# you can also send the request like this...

s = Session()
resp = s.send(prepped)
```